# Stale elements not getting resolved after waits, python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to go into every link on this page with the class of "course"

```
<a name="hrvatski-jezik" href="/pregled/predmet/29812177240/1971997880"><div class="course">
    Hrvatski jezik   <br>
        <span class="course-info">Tamara Čer</span>
    </div>
</a>
<a name="likovna-kultura" href="/pregled/predmet/29812176230/1971998890">
    <div class="course">Likovna kultura   <br>
        <span class="course-info">Mia  Marušić</span>
    </div>
</a>
<a name="glazbena-kultura" href="/pregled/predmet/29812175220/1971999900">
    <div class="course">Glazbena kultura   <br>
        <span class="course-info">Danijel Služek</span>
    </div>
</a>
<a name="engleski-jezik" href="/pregled/predmet/29820696590/1972511970">
    <div class="course">Engleski jezik   <br>
        <span class="course-info">Nevena Genčić</span>
    </div>
</a>    
<a name="matematika" href="/pregled/predmet/29812174210/1972000910">
    <div class="course">Matematika   <br>
        <span class="course-info">Ivan Tomljanović</span>
    </div></a>
<a name="biologija" href="/pregled/predmet/29812173200/1972001920">
    <div class="course">Biologija   <br>
        <span class="course-info">Antonija Milić</span>
    </div>
</a>
<a name="kemija" href="/pregled/predmet/29812172190/1972002930">
    <div class="course">Kemija   <br>
        <span class="course-info">Antonija Milić</span>
    </div>
</a>
<a name="fizika" href="/pregled/predmet/29812171180/1972003940">
    <div class="course">Fizika   <br>
        <span class="course-info">Ivan Kunac</span>
    </div>
</a>
<a name="povijest" href="/pregled/predmet/29812170170/1972004950">
    <div class="course">Povijest   <br>
        <span class="course-info">Lovorka Krajnović Tot</span>
    </div>
</a>
<a name="geografija" href="/pregled/predmet/29812169160/1972005960">
    <div class="course">Geografija   <br>
        <span class="course-info">Sunčica Podolski <strong> (na zamjeni)</strong>, Oliver Timarac</span>
    </div>
</a>
<a name="tehnicka-kultura" href="/pregled/predmet/29812168150/1972006970">
    <div class="course">Tehnička kultura   <br>
        <span class="course-info">Ivan Dorotek</span>
    </div>
</a>
<a name="tjelesna-i-zdravstvena-kultura" href="/pregled/predmet/29812167140/1972007980">
    <div class="course">Tjelesna i zdravstvena kultura   <br>
        <span class="course-info">Davor  Marković, Tomislav Ruskaj</span>
    </div>
</a>
<a name="informatika" href="/pregled/predmet/29821462170/1972568530">
    <div class="course">Informatika (izborni)  <br>
        <span class="course-info">Blaženka Knežević</span>
    </div>
</a>
<a name="njemacki-jezik" href="/pregled/predmet/32658461270/1972646300"><div class="course">Njemački jezik (izborni)  <br>
    <span class="course-info">Zdravka Marković Boto</span>
</div>
</a>
<a name="rusinski-jezik-i-kultura" href="/pregled/predmet/32658491570/1972675590">
    <div class="course">Rusinski jezik i kultura (izborni)  <br>
        <span class="course-info">Natalija Hnatko, Ilona Hrecešin</span>
    </div>
</a>
<a name="sat-razrednika" href="/pregled/predmet/32322897860/2140793120">
    <div class="course">Sat razrednika   <br>
        <span class="course-info">Blaženka Knežević</span>
    </div>
</a>
<a name="izvannastavne-aktivnosti" href="/pregled/predmet/34285616720/2324344460">
    <div class="course">Izvannastavne aktivnosti (izvannastavna aktivnost)  <br>
        <span class="course-info">Nevena Genčić, Ivan Kunac, Davor  Marković, Josip Matezović, Antonija Milić, Tomislav Ruskaj, Danijel Služek</span>
    </div>
</a>
```

`
I expect the code to go into every link, then go back and repeat.
It goes once into the try block and then 16 times into the except block.

For every except it gives `StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document`

My code:

```
def get_subject():

    subjects = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='course']")

    for subject in subjects: 
        actions = ActionChains(driver)
        actions.move_to_element(subject)    

        try:
            actions.click()
            actions.perform()

            driver.back()
            print("try")

            time.sleep(3)

        except Exception as e:
            subjects = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='course']")
            print("except")
            print(e)
```

I know this is a very common problem. I tried implicit and explicit waits, I still got the same error.
I tried `visibility_of_element_located`, `presence_of_element_located`, `staleness_of`, I tried defining "subjects" again.

Help would be really appreciated, I've been searching for a solution for some time now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest capture `all links` first and then iterate.

```
alllinks=[link.get_attribute('href') for link in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a[href^='/pregled/predmet']")]
for link in alllinks:
    driver.get(link)
    #Perform your operation
```

---

If you want to continue with your code just re-assigned the elements again.since you are using driver.back() your page is getting refreshed.

```
def get_subject():

    subjects = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='course']")

    for subject in range(len(subjects)):
        subjects = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='course']")
        actions = ActionChains(driver)
        actions.move_to_element(subjects[subject])    

        try:
            actions.click()
            actions.perform()

            driver.back()
            print("try")

            time.sleep(3)

        except Exception as e:
            subjects = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='course']")
            print("except")
            print(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

`actions.move_to_element(subject)` is the culprit here.

all the element references in the `subjects` will be refreshed when you click on the `subject` in your try block, that's why you are getting the `StateleElementException`.
Try changing the code as shown below.

```
def get_subject():

    subjects = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='course']"))

    for counter in range(subjects):
        subject = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("(//div[@class='course'])[" + str(counter) + "]") 
        actions = ActionChains(driver)
        actions.move_to_element(subject)    

        try:
            actions.click()
            actions.perform()

            driver.back()
            print("try")

            time.sleep(3)

        except Exception as e:
            print("except")
            print(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

driver.back() function doesn't guarantee to work. Instead, try using this driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)") and then re-assign the elements again inside your loop.

Comment: how does it resolves the stale element exception that OP mentioned in the post.

Comment: Could you explain why I should use driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")  instead of driver.back()?

Comment: I don't know about your website but there are some websites which when clicking on the back button refreshes the page instead of actually going back.